# Как получить значение переменной отсюда и использовать это значение для полезных дел, а не для вывода в консоль?

Tags: powershell, bat

Собственно код, взят тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885132/file-folder-chooser-dialog-from-a-windows-batch-script/15885133#15885133
Проблема в том, что данный код может только вывести результат в консоль, а мне бы очень хотелось использовать результат в моем батнике в качестве переменной, но никак. Бьюсь третий день с тривиальной задачей. Я вызываю этот батник из своего батника, если требуется выбрать файл, но получить значение переменной не выходит просто никак! ЧЯДНТ? Кроме `Echo` я от него ничего не смог добиться. Основной код:

```
@echo off&cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set working_directory=%~dp0
if %working_directory% NEQ %cd% (
set working_directory=%cd%
)
call chooser.bat :: Активируем выбор файла
set filename=!chose!
set "filename=%filename:~0,-12%" :: обрезка
echo Path to file %filename%
pause
```

Код для выбора файла.

```
<# : chooser.bat 
:: launches a File... Open sort of file chooser and outputs choice(s) to the console 
 
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"') do ( 
set "chose=%%~I" 
echo !chose! 
) 

goto :EOF 

: end Batch portion / begin PowerShell hybrid chimera #> 

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 
$f = new-object Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog 
$f.InitialDirectory = pwd 
$f.Filter = "Program executable (program.exe)|program.exe" 
$f.ShowHelp = $true 
$f.Multiselect = $false 
[void]$f.ShowDialog() 
if ($f.Multiselect) { $f.FileNames } else { $f.FileName }
```

Comment: А что вы хотите?  Ни в винде, ни в линуксе подпроцесс не может менять переменные окружения вызвавшего его процесса.  Вся обратная связь от подпроцессов - только через чтение их stdout.  Правда, в линуксе сделали команду source для обхода этого ограничения, а в винде её не сделали.

Comment: То есть только через костыль в виде записи stdout в файл и последующего чтения? Просто мне совершенно непонятен смысл этого конструкта... Я пытался весь свой скрипт запихнуть внутрь цикла - получил абсолютную ересь. Казалось бы вот оно, нужное значение, просто возьми... ан нет...

Comment: `Я пытался весь свой скрипт запихнуть внутрь цикла` - и зачем-то вынесли цикл в отдельный процесс и получили геморрой с межпроцессным взаимодействием.

Comment: вы всё равно в эту гадость (повершелл) вляпались, ну так и пишите тогда на нём весь скрипт целиком